# processing large data using multiple threads of same code in linux C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

can multiple threads of same function be created to process large arrays in small blocks?

i am trying to do it in Linux C, assume i have read() it is reading data from serial into array, when array is full it is passed for processing to stable(), meanwhile it is processed, read should be reading new data, because stable() is taking long to process old data, so newly created thread of stable() should be processing new data available in array.

problem is i am confused, can i create two threads of stable() in Linux C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each thread created using the pthreads API specifies an entry point that should match the standard signature:

```
void *entry(void *)
{
   return 0;
}
```

Once that entry point  has been called, you can invoke anything that you want including the stable() routine that you referenced above.  You will need to be careful, however, to ensure that stable() and anything that it calls is thread safe.